# Strange tax problem

Tags: magento-1.9, vat

I have a strange TAX problem on a dutch website.

- All prices are excl. VAT
- I have 3 different tax groups (None = 0%, Laag = 6% and Hoog = 21%
- I have 2 different customer groups. (BTW plichtig = with tax and BTW vrij = without tax).
- When adding a product to the shopping cart somehow it is not calculating the tax.

Subtotal = 4,64 = CORRECT
Shipping = 3,95 = CORRECT (shipping is excl. 21% tax)

Totaal excl Tax = 7,48 = WRONG

Tax = 1,11 = CORRECT (6% 0,28 and 21% 0,83)

Total = 8,59 = WRONG (this is the price excluding VAT)

[image]

Anyone a idea ? I double checked everything but cannot find the problem.

Thanks !

Comment: you have multistore view is there? that means multiple currency in your site?

Comment: no multistore. only one store. only one currency (euro)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tagged the question with 1.9 - is that with newest patches?  I had some problems with 1.9 in combination with php7 when it was first released and managed to fix it by implementing a patch to get topological sorting of the tax calculation 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11954867/653721

Full threads with more information:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9194281/sort-algorithm-magento-checkout-totals-sorted-wrongly-causing-wrong-shipping-ta

http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92783/magento-grand-total-without-taxes-in-1-9-with-php7